# FastAPI dependency override faild

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi, mongomock

I'm using MongoMock to test my FastAPI app, but I can' override FastAPI's Dependency.

The `create_test_data` will insert some fake test data with MongoMock' Client and return the `task_id` which is need by api request.

```py
from mongomock import MongoClient
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from pytest import fixture
from app import app
from core.utils.db_utils import get_db
from models.tasks import TaskCreate
from models.frequency import Frequency


@fixture(name="conn")
def conn_fixture():
    with MongoClient() as conn:
        yield conn


@fixture(name="client")
def client_fixture(conn: MongoClient):
    def get_conn_override():
        return conn

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = get_conn_override

    client = TestClient(app)
    yield client
    app.dependency_overrides.clear()


def test_wrong_api_log(conn: MongoClient, client: TestClient):
    task_id = create_test_data(conn=conn, platform="test")
    assert task_id
    
    response = client.get(url=f"/api/tasks/{task_id}")
    assert response.text
```

In "test_wrong_api_log" function, the first assert with task_id can pass, but the second one, can't pass seems like override FastAPI's dependency faild cause.

Following code is `get_db`, the `connect_to_mongo` will return an pymongo's MongoClient not MongoMock's MongoClient.

```
from db.mongodb_utils import connect_to_mongo


def get_db():
    db_client = connect_to_mongo()
    try:
        yield db_client
    finally:
        db_client.close()
```

Is there anyway to resolve this problem?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to diagnose the issue or reproduce it.

Comment: You neither ever call your `client_fixture` in your test nor put it in params annotation. So you never override it.

Comment: @danangjoyoo I use `@fixture(name="client")` to named `client_fixtrue`. Isn't this the proper way to use it?

Comment: I wrote my answer in comment session below, tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: @flakes sorry about that, but would like to ask what more information I need to provide

Comment: Have you verified whether `get_conn_override` runs at all? i.e. is it an issue with the dependency override or with what the function returns?

Answer (score 0):

You neither ever call your `client_fixture`. In addition, your `conn` should call your fixture too.

Try this

```
def test_wrong_api_log(conn_fixture: MongoClient, client_fixture: TestClient):
    task_id = create_test_data(conn=conn_fixture, platform="test")
    assert task_id
    
    response = client_fixture.get(url=f"/api/tasks/{task_id}")
    assert response.text
```

Comment: Hmm.. it seems not work, the error message told me "pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError"

Comment: sorry, i'm just fixed it for you just now. I change the params and some of your code in my answer. Maybe you can tried it again?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it still has an error, bellow is error message.`fixture 'client_fixture' not found`

Comment: what if you define `@fixture` without `name` params?

Comment: I have'd try it, but still not work